# jQuery concatenate custom function

Tags: jquery

I need to call a custom function after i toggle all my items. Not for each one.

Lets say we have an alert:

```
function myAlert() { alert("OK"); }
```

If I code like this, it calls for each time it toggles:

```
$('div.myGroupOfItems').toggle('fast',function() {
myAlert();
});
```

How can I do it like this, since mine is a custom JS function? This way it doesn't work:

```
$('div.myGroupOfItems').toggle('fast').myAlert();
```

Or other solutions?

Comment: To add a .myAlert() method to a jQuery object see http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this from jQuery 1.6 onwards...

```
$('div.myGroupOfItems').toggle('fast');

$('div.myGroupOfItems').promise().done(function() {
    myAlert();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

You would have to extend jQuery to add your method to it. You can do it like this:

```
$.fn.myAlert = function () {
    alert("OK");
};
```

If you want to be able to chain other jQuery methods after that, you need to return `this` from the plugin.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/MUsP2/).

---

If you're interested in what that actually does in a bit more detail, read on. `$.fn` is simply an alias for `$.prototype`. By adding a property to the `prototype`, you're effectively extending all jQuery instances.

When you call `$`, jQuery internally creates an instance (you don't need to create an instance manually e.g. with the `new` operator). Since you've extended `$.prototype`, all instances will now have access to your new method.

If you use the code exactly as I've shown it above (with no `return` statement) you won't be able to chain further calls to jQuery methods. By returning the instance from the method, calls will be chainable:

```
$.fn.myAlert = function () {
    alert("OK");
    return this;
};
```

Note that inside the method, `this` refers to a jQuery instance, so there's no need to wrap it in an unnecessary call to `$`.

Comment: It's not all about the custom jquery function... He can't use this 'cause the toggle function is executed assync. Meaning it will alert before everything's done.

Comment: @VDP - Ah, good point. In that case, OP, look at ATOzTOA's answer. If you want a combination of the two, cache a reference to the jQuery object and call `myAlert` on that from inside the callback.

Comment: i'm going to try ATOzTOA's answer but i can i call my function directly, like on window load after using your code? this way doesn't work $.myAlert()

Comment: @al404 - No, the idea with my code is that you extend jQuery *instances*. You can only call it on a jQuery object returned by `$` (e.g. `$("#something").myAlert()`). If you need to call it at other times, it's probably easier to use ATOzTOA's answer.

Answer (score 4):

To use that syntax you would need to make your function into a jQuery plugin like this:

```
$.fn.extend({         
    myAlert: function() {
        alert('OK');
        return this; // return the assigned elements to continue chaining.
    }
});

$('div.myGroupOfItems').toggle('fast').myAlert();
```

Comment: @Nile - No, since `fn` is just an alias for `prototype`, `this` will refer to a jQuery instance.